# Logical disjunction of a list of booleans represented by integers

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have two arraylists: a1 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,} and a2 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}. I need to compare the elements of both the arraylists so I can come up with a3 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}.

a3 is based on the Logical disjunction operation where *it produces a value of true if at least one of its operands is true.*

need help here...

Comment: Why use integers to store boolean values? Why not use BitSets, which provide an `or()` method?

Comment: @JBNizet Because homework doesn't always have to make sense.

Comment: If you merge the answer of me and Anshu, you will know how...and even have the code to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there could be better solutions, but the following should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 };
        List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(a);
        Integer[] b = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
        List<Integer> a2 = Arrays.asList(b);
        List<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            a3.add(a1.get(i) | a2.get(i));
            System.out.print(a3.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
111100
```

Comment: thank you for the reply ... what if I had ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>(); how can i convert it to List<Integer> ?? because it gives me an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ArrayList<String>> to List<Integer>" when I try to convert 
List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(array1);

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple for loop that iterates over both array's and you "OR" both values, and your done...

Best you chect both arrays to be equal length before you start...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a1 and a2 have the same lengths and that they only hold elements of 1 or 0:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> LogicalDisjunction(ArrayList<Integer> a1, ArrayList<Integer> a2) {
    Assert(a1.length == a2.length);

    ArrayList<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if ( ( a1.get(i) == 1 ) || ( a2.get(i) == 1) ) {
            a3.add(1);
        } else {
            a3.add(0);
        }
    }
    return a3;
}
```

Comment: Why not just [`a3[i] = a1[i] | a2[i]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)?

Comment: Does Java not warn you if you try to save a Boolean into an Integer object without a cast of some sort?

Comment: A bitwise or on two `int`s gives you an `int`.

Comment: int is not the same as Integer object. Is there automatic type conversion from Integer to int on the bitwise 'or', as well as assignment?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: It is possibly faster to compare the hash value and note you will get a false result for either method if the arrays contain the same elements in different orders, so a sort operation may be prudent; 
  Collections.sort(arr1);
  Collections.sort(arr2);

  if (arr1.hashCode() == arr2.hashCode()) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }